# Recurly : Get Account Info from Email Id

Tags: recurly

I am using Recurly to handle subscriptions.
Before I show the payment form, I need to know if the logged-in user is already subscribed.

The docs at https://dev.recurly.com/docs/get-account say account_code :

`try {
  $account = Recurly_Account::get('1');
  print "Account: $account\n";
} catch (Recurly_NotFoundError $e) {
  print "Account not found.\n";
}`

But Im trying to find out a call similar to this :

`$account = Recurly_Account::get($User->Email);`

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can achieve this simply by `$account = Recurly_Account::get($User->Email);`
EDIT : The above will work *only* if the email address is the **account_code**.

```
$found = FALSE;
$accounts = Recurly_AccountList::get();
foreach ($accounts as $account)
{
    if ($account->email == $User->Email)
    {
        $found = TRUE;
        # Do Something
    }
}
# print_r($account);
```